# Loading dll file

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

Whenever I have some changes regarding my DLL project, it's obvious that the dll file is having as well some changes.

But? Since I "load" it in an APP, it was saying to me that it's missing from my computer. The error has been fixed by copying and pasting the generated dll file in C:\Windows , which is not a good idea to do everytime I make changes in the dll file.

Is there a code algorithm that would copy everytime my file.dll into the folder of Windows?

Comment: Not sure but can't you include that dll file in your program while compiling ?

Comment: 1) what method of dll loading do you use and 2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx aka just put the dll in the same directory as the exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your situation is:

- If you have dll and app projects in the same solution, mark app as dependent project and make them both put binaries into the same folder.
- Otherwise, add post-build step to your dll project to copy dll file to the same folder where app exe file is located.
- Or, add the location of your dll to `PATH` environment variable.